# from 2d window coordinates to 3d world coordinates with opengl and gluUnProject function

Tags: java, android, 3d, opengl-es, raycasting

I've got a pair of window coordinates taken from a screen touch and I'm trying to retrive the 3d coordinates for calculate the distance between another point in a large point cloud.
I used gluUnProject function but I don't think that I set the correct parameter for my use case.
Here is my code:

```
public Vector3f raycast(float x, float y) {

            GLU.gluUnProject(x, screenHeight - y, 0f, mVMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, new int[]{0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight}, 0, resultNear, 0);
            fixW(resultNear);

            GLU.gluUnProject(x, screenHeight - y, 1000f, mVMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, new int[]{0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight}, 0, resultFar, 0);
            fixW(resultFar);

            Vector3f rayDirection = new Vector3f(resultFar[0] - resultNear[0], resultFar[1] - resultNear[1], resultFar[2] - resultNear[2]);
            //rayDirection.normalize();
            System.out.print(rayDirection.x + " ray ");
            System.out.print(rayDirection.y + " ray ");
            System.out.print(rayDirection.z + " ray\n");
            return rayDirection;
        }

        private float computeDistance(float x1,float y1,float z1,float x2,float y2,float z2){

            return (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2-x1),2) + Math.pow((y2-y1),2) + Math.pow((z2-z1),2));
        }

        private void fixW(float[] v) {
            float w = v[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                v[i] = v[i] / w;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
            GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
            screenWidth = width;
            screenHeight = height;

            // this projection matrix is applied to object coodinates
            // in the onDrawFrame() method
            Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1f, 1000f);
            GLES20.glDepthRangef(-1,-1000);
            muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
            Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 , centerX, centerY, centerZ, 0f, 1f, 0f);
            Matrix.translateM(mVMatrix,0,mVMatrix,0,centerX,centerY,centerZ);
        }
```

I'm not sure how to correctly use the zNear and zFar parameters.Moreover,I didn't calculate the normalized point cloud coordinates to set the model, projection and view matrix, my points aren't in the [0,1] range, they have the initial word coordinates.

Here is the part of the onDrawFrame method where I use the distance:

```
         Vector3f rayFirstTouch = new Vector3f();
         Vector3f raySecondTouch = new Vector3f();
         rayFirstTouch = raycast(touches[0], touches[1]); //x,y coord of first screen touch
         raySecondTouch = raycast(touches[2], touches[3]);
         float distance = computeDistance(rayFirstTouch.x,rayFirstTouch.y,rayFirstTouch.z,raySecondTouch.x,raySecondTouch.y,raySecondTouch.z );
         System.out.println("distance: " + distance);
```

I tried to plot the points that gluUnproject function maps but the screen didn't show anything

[This is the line(green shape) that I saw, It isn't what I expected because the line should be between the two point that I clicked on the point cloud, not anywhere in the space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsfOW.png)